# Connecting Azure MobileServiceClient with local backend

Tags: javascript, azure, asp.net-web-api

I want to debug a WebApi Client Project.

The client sample comes - ready to use - from Azure. I configure it to use my local WebAPI backend by changing the line that says

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://myproject-code.azurewebsites.net', 'https://someGateWay.azurewebsites.net', '');
```

to

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('http://localhost:59477/', '', '');
```

As you see, the API runs on port 59477. When I refresh the client (Port 4400), it queries the API and runs into a CORS Exception:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

How can I set this up to develop and debug the server and client locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this because I normally use the JavaScript backend for my Mobile Apps, but you just need to tell the Mobile App to allow localhost to access it via CORS. This article on [Azure Mobile Services .NET Adds CORS Support, Better Authentication](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/07/29/azure-mobile-cors.aspx) should get you there.